# Index not starting at zero when using PANDAS iterrows() in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm running a loop where I iterate through a DataFrame and append an item to a list at each iteration.  The code is like this:

```
    l=[]

    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        print len(l)
        print i
        l.append(df['A'])
```

Getting a situation where i and len(l) are not equal, and i may be different in subsequent runs.

My assumption was that i was an integer that increments by one each iteration and starts at zero, but this seems to be incorrect.

So, what defines the value of i for each iteration in the loop?

Comment: Have you tried checking the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)? The `iterrows` iterator returns a `tuple`, which has the index value for that row, and a `pd.Series` representing the row.

Comment: It's pretty much `for i, vs in zip(df.index, df.values): yield i, pd.Series(vs)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thanks so if I wanted to have i start at zero and increment each time I could just df.reset_index.  Thanks

Comment: That or `for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a DataFrame with `iterrows` gives `(index, Series)` pairs for each row, as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). However, *index* in Pandas doesn't always mean 0 to whatever.

Every row of a Pandas DataFrame has a label, also known as its index. These labels are frequently integers from 0 to the number of rows in the DataFrame, but the labels can be almost anything:

```
>>> x = pandas.DataFrame(index=[1, 'apples', object()], data={'x': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> x
                                   x
1                                  1
apples                             2
<object object at 0x7f25cdb16b50>  3
```

Here, I have a DataFrame with row labels `1`, `'apples'`, and an instance of `object`. These are the indices you will see with `iterrows`:

```
>>> [i for i, row in x.iterrows()]
[1, 'apples', <object object at 0x7f25cdb16b50>]
```

Indexes can be even more complicated than that with [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)es, but this should be enough for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments section this is just the index.

Thank you.